# Windows Vista Home: Error Profile cannot be load?

Tags: windows-vista, user-profiles

On a Windows Vista home are two user-acounts one with administrator-proîviledge and annother one as a user.
Now it happens that the account with admin-rights doesn't work anymore: Profile not loading...

What can be done to bring this thing-a-magic to fly again?

Comment: Have you tried restarting?

Answer (score 1):

This article might help:

[How to Fix the Error "The User Profile Service failed the logon. User profile cannot be loaded"](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/130095-user-profile-service-failed-logon-user-profile-cannot-loaded.html) :

> The jury is still out on the exact
>   cause, but so far :
>
> - This issue may occur if the user profile was manually deleted by using
>     the command prompt or Windows Explorer
>     by a user or by some program. A
>     profile that is manually deleted does
>     not remove the security identifier
>     (SID) from the user profile list in
>     the registry. Since the SID is still
>     present, Vista will still try to load
>     the profile by using the
>     ProfileImagePath that points to a
>     nonexistent path. Therefore, the
>     profile cannot be loaded.
> - This can also be a issue with the user profile entering into a backup
>     state.
> - Manually renamed the C:\Users(User Name) folder.

The article then lists several methods of fixing the problem.

Comment: Quick comment - have used [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307545) multiple times on windows XP systems to fix filesystem errors/viruses/corruption from faulting hard drives. Unsure if there's similar for Vista and not got time to check! :)